# Сослагательное наклонение в конструкции "даже если"

Tags: грамматика

*Ни один мужчина его времени, боясь показаться смешным, не рискнул бы выглядеть молодым в его возрасте, **даже если считал себя таковым или был им на самом деле**.*

Выделенный фрагмент в тексте оригинала стоит в сослагательном наклонении. Как можно объяснить то, что переводчик передаёт реальным фактом то, что автор текста считает гипотетическим? 
Это допустимо?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Ни один мужчина его времени, боясь показаться смешным, не рискнул бы выглядеть молодым в его возрасте, **даже если (= хотя бы)** считал себя таковым или был им на самом деле.

Я полагаю, что это СПП с придаточным предположительной (ирреальной) уступки, при этом условный формант "даже если" заменяет союз "хотя бы", поэтому придаточное сохраняет свое гипотетическое значение и при отсутствии частицы БЫ.

Answer (score 1):

> Как можно объяснить то, что переводчик передаёт реальным фактом то,
>   что автор текста считает гипотетическим?

Я, признаться, не вижу здесь (в выделенным) ни "реального факта", ни "гипотетического".

Реальный (с точки зрения повествователя) факт: ни один мужчина не рискнул... "Не рискнул бы" - не имеет сослагательного оттенка, "бы" здесь частица, которую можно трактовать как усилительную или наоборот уступительную - в зависимости от окончания фразы.

А касательно того, что выделено...

Как и во всех подобных случаях, грамматическая конструкция сослагательного наклонения используется для передачи значения, не имеющего прямого условного значения.

Вот основные модальные виды действий сослагательного наклонения: возможное,  предположительное, желательное и описываемое. Здесь - возможное. В категориях русской грамматики - уступки. (Реальной или ирреальной - это отдельный разговор).

Конкретику я опускаю, см. Sybilla

Answer (score 1):

Дело в реалистичности условия в обороте с "даже" - оно *не гипотетическое*: вариант с "бы" был бы почти эквивалентен абсурдному утверждению, что среди мужчин его времени в его возрасте никто не считал себя молодым или не был им на самом деле. Без данной же частицы автор только подчёркивает, что относит к группе мужчин того времени и сформулированного гипотетического поведения (в его возрасте не рискнул бы, не хотел и пр. - такие взгляды бытовали) даже ту их часть, из которой каждый считал себя молодым или был им. Нет здесь и причинно-следственных связей типа "если бы... то вышло бы". Более наглядной ненужность "бы" становится при простом изменении порядка слов:

> Ни один мужчина его времени, даже если он считал себя молодым или был
>   им на самом деле, не рискнул бы выглядеть молодым в его возрасте,
>   боясь показаться смешным.

Однако если бы условие было заведомо нереальным ("даже если был космонавтом" в прошлом веке), отсутствие частицы "бы" стало бы грамматической ошибкой - из такой конструкции следовало бы невозможное (были тогда и космонавты).

Comment: *Дело в реалистичности условия в обороте с "даже" - оно не гипотетическое: вариант с "бы" был бы почти эквивалентен абсурдному утверждению,* - совершено фантастическая трактовка. На чем вы основываете свой вывод об абсурдности - и вообще о семантике фразы?

Comment: На чём? На том, что оборот "даже если бы было так" неизбежно подразумевает утверждение "на самом деле было не так", поэтому вариант, в котором вы либерально усматриваете "некоторое нарушение грамматики", для меня просто косноязычен - он разрушает смысл, который пытаются донести.

Comment: Либеральность здесь ни при чем. Это грамматика. А у вас какие-то странные мысли. Я имел в виду, что вы мне укажете на источник своего подхода, а вы мне про "косноязычие". Вы еще и невнимательны к тому же. Я усмотрел нарушение грамматики (предположительно, не берусь утвеждать, что я на все 100% прав) не там, где вы видите абсурдность, а в исходном  варианте, в том, который вы считаете единственно правильном. Ибо отсутствие "бы" там нарушает логику построения... Это так, к слову...   )))

Comment: Только сейчас заметил, что  возможные грамматические проблемы вы усматриваете в правильном варианте. Тогда  это просто ошибка, которую я уже объяснил вариантом с изменением порядка слов, из которого невозможность второго "бы" очевидна.

Answer (score 0):

Варианты

***даже если считал себя таковым или был им на самом деле***

и

***даже если бы считал себя таковым или был бы им на самом деле***

Абсолютно тождественны по смыслу. Просто одно "бы" уже есть в начале фразы, поэтому второе ничего не добавляет и может быть опущено. Хотя возможно тут и есть некоторое нарушение грамматики в первом случае.

> Как можно объяснить то, что переводчик передаёт реальным фактом то, что автор текста считает гипотетическим?

***Объяснять*** перевод можно и нужно тогда, когда есть вопросы по точности перевода или его качеству. В данном случае таких вопросов не поставлено, да и сравнивать не с чем, исходного текста нет.